# Best way to match function inside an Object - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

What I want is to call openMenu function when click bars, and closeMenu function when click close icon.

I noticed that ***icon.callFunc == openMenu*** is always false. [Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urbiF.png)

This is the source for whole component.

```
const MenuBar = () => {

    const onPressHandler = () => {

        setIcon({
            icon: icon.icon === 'bars'? "window-close" : 'bars',
            callFunc: icon.callFunc == openMenu ? closeMenu : openMenu
        });
        console.log(icon.callFunc);
        icon.callFunc()

    }

    const closeMenu = () => {
        console.log("Closed");
    }

    const openMenu = () => {
        console.log("Opened");
    }


    const [icon, setIcon] = useState({
        icon: "bars",
        callFunc: openMenu
    })


    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={onPressHandler}>
            
            <Icon
                name={icon.icon}
                size={25}
                color="white"
                solid
                style={{ paddingLeft: 14, padding: 20 }} />

        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I guess you should use `icon.callFunc === openMenu`, instead of `icon.callFunc == openMenu`. If your types are different, `==` will fail

Comment: Tried that also, did not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be using state to manage whether your menu is showing or not as per @Tarukami's suggestion.

If you really want to use this route, you can try checking the functions name instead of its reference, which may be different.

```
  const onPressHandler = () => {
    setIcon({
      icon: icon.icon === "bars" ? "window-close" : "bars",
      callFunc: icon.callFunc.name === "openMenu" ? closeMenu : openMenu
    });
    console.log(icon.callFunc);
    icon.callFunc();
  };
```

I would suggest then initialising your icon within a "componentDidMount" useEffect.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setIcon({
      icon: "bars",
      callFunc: openMenu
    });
  }, []);
```

Full code is as follows

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = (props) => {
  const closeMenu = () => {
    console.log("Closed");
  };

  const openMenu = () => {
    console.log("Opened");
  };

  const [icon, setIcon] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setIcon({
      icon: "bars",
      callFunc: openMenu
    });
  }, []);

  const onPressHandler = () => {
    setIcon({
      icon: icon.icon === "bars" ? "window-close" : "bars",
      callFunc: icon.callFunc.name === "openMenu" ? closeMenu : openMenu
    });
    console.log(icon.callFunc);
    icon.callFunc();
  };

  return <div onClick={onPressHandler}>fokoff</div>;
};

export default App;
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-ritchie-v22ns?file=/src/App.js), notice the "Opened" and "Closed" toggling in the console.

It is also important to note that the setIcon method is async, so even though you are setting icon.callFunc to openMenu, because it was "closeMenu", "closeMenu" will still be fired at icon.callFunc(), and openMenu will be fired on the next call of onPressHandler.

Comment: `icon.callFunc.name === "openMenu" ? closeMenu : openMenu` This works for me! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to make the things way much complex than they are. Take a look at this simple template showing and hiding Menu component:

```
const Menu = () => {
  return <h3>Hi I am the menu</h3>
}
const App = () => {
  const [isMenuVisible, setIsMenuVisible] = useState(false)
  function handleClick() {
    setIsMenuVisible(!isMenuVisible)
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick} >{isMenuVisible ? "Hide menu" : "Show menu"}</button>
      {isMenuVisible && <Menu />}
    </>
    )
}
```

I am pretty sure it is much easier to read and use in your application.

Comment: This is really simple! Must have a try